# How Use Custom Column in Select Sql Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select sql command like under:

```
SELECT Title,G ,K ,M,
 CASE 
     WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 AND tblMain.K <> 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G AND tblCustomer.K = tblMain.K)
     WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 AND tblMain.K = 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G)
     ELSE 0 
 END AS B1,
 CASE 
     WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 tblMain.K <> 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G AND tblCustomer.K = tblMain.K)
     WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 AND tblMain.K = 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G)
     else 0 
 END AS S1,
 (S1 - B1) AS Result
FROM tblMain
```

but my probelm is that, the "(S1 - B1) AS Result" statement does not work and get me under error:

```
Invalid column name 'S1'.
Invalid column name 'B1'.
```

how can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with SubQuery as
(

    SELECT Title,G ,K ,M,
     CASE 
         WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 AND tblMain.K <> 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G AND tblCustomer.K = tblMain.K)
         WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 AND tblMain.K = 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G)
         ELSE 0 
     END AS B1,
     CASE 
         WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 tblMain.K <> 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G AND tblCustomer.K = tblMain.K)
         WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 AND tblMain.K = 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G)
         else 0 
     END AS S1
    FROM tblMain
)
select e.*,  (e.S1 - e.B1) AS Result  from SubQuery e
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reuse the aliases this way. You can use a subquery tho:

```
SELECT Title,G ,K ,M, B1, S1, (S1 - B1) AS Result FROM

(SELECT Title,G ,K ,M,
 CASE 
     WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 AND tblMain.K <> 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G AND tblCustomer.K = tblMain.K)
     WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 AND tblMain.K = 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G)
     ELSE 0 
 END AS B1,
 CASE 
     WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 tblMain.K <> 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G AND tblCustomer.K = tblMain.K)
     WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 AND tblMain.K = 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G)
     else 0 
 END AS S1
FROM tblMain) TMP
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't seem to need the intermediate values you can just calc the result directly.

```
SELECT Title,G ,K ,M,
 CASE 
     WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 tblMain.K <> 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G AND tblCustomer.K = tblMain.K)
     WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 AND tblMain.K = 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G)
     else 0 
 END -  CASE 
     WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 AND tblMain.K <> 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G AND tblCustomer.K = tblMain.K)
     WHEN (tblMain.G <> 0 AND tblMain.K = 0 AND tblMain.M = 0) then (select sum(price) from tblCustomer where tblCustomer.G = tblMain.G)
     ELSE 0 
 END AS Result
FROM tblMain
```